# Autofac.Mef and WinRT

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, autofac

I'm having troubles while trying to add the Metadata of Autofac. I have to install the package "Autofac Extras: Metadata Attribute Support" which need Autofac.Mef. When installing this package, I get a message saying that I try to install Autofac.Mef 4.0.0 in a project targeting «portable-net45+win+wpa81» and that the package doesn't contain any file supporting this. (Same message with Autofac.Mef 3.0.3).

I could probably find a way to make my project work without Autofac's Metadata but I don't understand why this package isn't compatible with Windows Phone 8.1. Is there a solution to this issue?

Thanks in advance

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[If you download the Autofac.Mef package manually](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Mef) and then open it up in [NuGet Package Explorer](http://npe.codeplex.com/) you'll see that the Autofac.Mef package only targets .NET 4.5 apps - you can't use it in Windows Phone.

The reason for this is that the original framework MEF is only compatible with the full .NET framework. There's [a "lighter weight" MEF 2 framework that is compatible with Windows Phone 8.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Composition/) but that's not the one Autofac.Mef works with.

There's no way to fix it. There's also no current plan to switch Autofac.Mef to using the Microsoft.Composition package.

Comment: OK. I'll have to use the other solution which is less flexible then. Thanks for the answer :)